# How to plot a polar function with two variable?

Tags: plotting, visualization, coordinate-transformation

The expression in polar coordinate is

```
LGo[l_, m_, V_, R_, ϕ_] := R^l LaguerreL[m - 1, l, V R^2] Exp[-1/2 V R^2] Cos[l ϕ];
```

where l,m,V are parameters, and R,phi are variable.
 However, It can't be visualized by Polar Plot.

Is there any way to show it？

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways. One easy solution is to create a `Table` for several radii and plot them or use them in a `Manipulate`

```
LGo[l_, m_, V_, R_, ϕ_] := 
  R^l LaguerreL[m - 1, l, V R^2] Exp[-1/2 V R^2] Cos[l ϕ];

Manipulate[
 With[{expr = Table[LGo[l, m, V, r, phi], {r, 0.1, 1, 0.1}]},
  PolarPlot[expr, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}]
  ],
 {l, 1, 2},
 {m, 1, 2},
 {V, 1, 2}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you, but it seems that the result is not the same as desired.
Is there any way to transform the expression to Cartesian coordinate and use ContourPlot ?

Answer (score 0):

In response to OP's comment,

> Is there any way to transform the expression to Cartesian coordinate and use `ContourPlot`?

```
R1 = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
ϕ = ArcTan[y/x];
LGo[l_, m_, V_, R_, ϕ_] := R1^l LaguerreL[m - 1, l, V R1^2] Exp[-1/2 V R1^2] Cos[l ϕ];
Manipulate[ ContourPlot[LGo[l, m, V, x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
                        PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {l, 1, 2}, {m, 1, 2}, {V, 1, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I have replace R and phi to x and y by the converter formula directly. The result is correct now.